# jQuery: 4 space has been added to variable when I translate it by post

Tags: php, jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
 <div id=test></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var posting = $.post( 'saveInfos.php', list, function(data){
    $('#test').html(data);
    getModal(data,false);
});
```

**PHP(*saveInfos.php*):**

```
$request = "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (...,...,...)";

if ($pdo->exec($request)) {
    echo 'succes';
}
else{
    echo 'error';
}
```

**$('#test').html(); returns :**

> string 'succes    ' (length=9)

4 spaces had been added to `$('#test').html()`

**This question is Corrected***

Comment: if you want to prevent space to insert then user `ctype_space()`

Comment: Do you have a closing php tag with spaces / new-lines behind it? By the way, how is the output of th php script related to to `$_POST['E']`?

Comment: @Mr.Developer `ctype_space()` return if  consists of whitespace or not

Comment: @jgetner the output has nothing to do with $_POST

Comment: @jeroen all tags are closed

Comment: @jgetner i also try it

Comment: @jgetner how can that be? Op is echoing a hard coded string

Comment: Totally wrong window disrgard what i was saying it was related to another post.

Comment: Does your php file end in php mode?  I.e. a `<?php` then maybe some code but no `?>`  if not you probably have whitespace after leaving PHP mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP file has some spaces at the end, after your echo. You could trim it, but that would hide the actual problem, not solve it.

I prefer returning JSON results, which give you more possibilities and doesnt have this problem. It is a little more complex, but well worth it, especially when your code gets even a bit more advanced. In my example below, I've also added a error message:

```
$result = [];
if ($pdo->exec($request)) {
    $result['success'] = true;
} else{
    $result['success'] = false;
    $result['msg'] = "Foo and Bar went wrong.";
}
echo json_encode($result); // @javascript you do JSON.parse(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is whitespace in the file

Either `trim()` the response string or use json output which is far more reliable to work with

```
data = data.trim();
console.log(data.length)
$('#test').html(data);
```